# Mongo indexes on Arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo document as below. Here, projects will be like the first project will be on array index 0, second project on array index 1, third project on array index 2,....

```
{
  "_id": "234463456453643563456",
  "name": "Mike",
  "empId": "10",
  "managerId": "8",
  "projects" : [ "123", "456", "789"]
}
```

I have index on projects field and I would like to search employees whose first project is 123, second project is 456, ...

I have index as follows,

```
createIndex({"projects":1});
```

When I search like the below, it takes time.

> { "$or" : [ { "projects.2" : "123"} , { "projects.4" : "456"} , {
>   "projects.3" : "789"} , { "projects.1" : "5467"} , { "projects.0" :
>   "9768"}]}

But, the same query works very well after creating indexes like, it is really fast.

```
createIndex({"projects.0":1});
createIndex({"projects.1":1});
createIndex({"projects.2":1});
createIndex({"projects.3":1});
createIndex({"projects.4":1});
createIndex({"projects.5":1});
```

It saves 3 secs for each query after creating the index.

How does it work internally? Why is there this much difference?

Comment: Note that creating an index for each array entry is probably not a good long-term solution. There may be an alternative way to solve what you're trying to do. Does the project ordering matter? If you're interested, could you describe in detail what you require, along with your MongoDB version?

Comment: My mongo version is 3.4. Yes, the ordering is important based on project priority. I am curious to know the alternative solution and would like to understand why index an each array entry is not a good long term solution.

Comment: Could you open a new question with the relevant details please (e.g. use case, example documents, example outputs, MongoDB version, etc.)? I believe the question you have here was answered correctly by @Akrion, since the original question was about the indexing process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is easy to see how it works if you use the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/index.html) command. Here is a quick summary:

My test collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7fa665844b5ebfad064b1c"),
    "arr" : [ "123", "456", "789"]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b80f96e9fceda195ba853af"),
    "arr" : [ "ABC", "DEF", "FOO"]
}
```

My index: `createIndex({"arr":1})`

Now if I do a search as `find({arr: '123'}).explain()` we would see from the `explain result`:

```
...
"indexName" : "_arr_",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"multiKeyPaths" : {
    "arr" : [ 
        "arr"
    ]
},
...
```

That the correct index was used. Now what about `find({arr.0: '123'}).explain()`?

```
...
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
    "filter" : {
        "arr.0" : {
            "$eq" : "123"
        }
    },
    "direction" : "forward"
},
...
```

Well now we get a lovely full `COLLSCAN` as the "winning" plan :).

Next `createIndex({"arr.0":1});` and then `find({arr.0: '123'}).explain()` gives us:

```
...
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
            "arr.0" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "_arr.0_",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
            "arr.0" : []
        },
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
            "arr.0" : [ 
                "[\"123\", \"123\"]"
            ]
        }
    }
}
...
```

So as you can see the multiKey index on the `arr` is not enough if you are going to search by array index since:

> MongoDB creates an index key for each element in the array. These
>   multikey indexes support efficient queries against array fields

So this is exactly what happens when you do the initial index ... mongo finds the document which contains the `123` but in your case you want to get to the specific array index query for which you need a single index as shown by the `explain`.

Hope this helps you.